# Prevent createIndex if createTable

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

- Grails 2.1.1
- Database-Migration 1.2

When executing a `dbm-gorm-diff`, new tables get defined with a `createTable`.  Indexes for said table are created with the `CREATE` statement.  Liquibase also adds a `createIndex` for the table which errors out because the index already exists.  Simply removing these from the changelog fixes the problem.

Is there a way to tell the plugin / liquibase to not generate `createIndex` changeSets when a `createTable` exists?  Or do I just need to keep removing them?